# How can we select not common columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to select all the columns from two tables let us say Table A and Table B where A's Column Name is not equal to B's Column Name. I try to find a solution but all i find is how to get common columns.

```
select A.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS A
join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
on A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
where A.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
and B.TABLE_NAME = 'table2'
```

I don't want all those columns to be appeared whose name is common, but want all other columns whose name is not same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH A AS(
select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
),
B AS(
select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'table2'
)
SELECT A.COLUMN_NAME FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE B.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT B.COLUMN_NAME FROM A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE A.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted

Comment: This will give the column names which are in `A` not in `B` as well as those which are in `B` not in `A`. so the question should be like `Table A and Table B where A's Column Name is not equal to B's Column Name and vice versa` otherwise Mikael's query is also good.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated `not exists` in the where clause to get columns from Table1 that is not exist in Table2.

```
select A.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A
where A.TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' and
      not exists (
                 select *
                 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as B
                 where A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME and
                       B.TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
                 )
```

To get the columns from both tables you can use the above query twice and combine the result with a `union all`.

```
select A.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A
where A.TABLE_NAME = 'Table1' and
      not exists (
                  select *
                  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as B
                  where A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME and
                        B.TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
                     )
union all
select A.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A
where A.TABLE_NAME = 'Table2' and
      not exists (
                  select *
                  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as B
                  where A.COLUMN_NAME = B.COLUMN_NAME and
                        B.TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
                     )
```

Or you can use `except` with `union all`.

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from (
     select COLUMN_NAME
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     where TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
     except
     select COLUMN_NAME
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A
     where TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
     ) as C
union all
select COLUMN_NAME
from (
     select COLUMN_NAME
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     where TABLE_NAME = 'Table2'
     except
     select COLUMN_NAME
     from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as A
     where TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
     ) as C
```